# Force http protocol in Javascript file from local protocol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, iframe

We are using HTML5 to develope an phone app, which means that our local protocol on the phone is **file://**. We are trying to include Opentable's widget on our page for now. But their widget JS link looks like:

```
<script type='text/javascript> src='//secure.opentable.com/widget/reservation/loader?rid=27763&domain=com&type=standard&theme=standard&lang=en&overlay=false&iframe=true'></script>
```

Note that it starts with

```
//secure.opentable.com
```

So it will get our **file://** protocol automatically. But even I change it to

```
https://secure.opentable.com
```

It still does not work on local. I noticed that in their JS source, they still used "//" which will somehow still get our "file://" protocol.

Here is the error after I change the link to **https://secure.opentable.com/...**

> Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this
>   server.
>
> file://www.opentable.com/widget/reservation/canvas?rid=27763&domain=com&type=standard&theme=standard&lang=en&overlay=false&insideiframe=true

I noticed that in the console it looks like:

[image]

How can I make it work for a local environment?

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get when you try `https://secure.opentable.com`? It should work like that.

Comment: @Barmar I put the error in my question. Look at the yellow highlighted section. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error is coming from their script. It creates an iframe, and they don't put a protocol in the iframe's source, so it uses the same protocol as your page. You need to contact them to find out if there's a way to make it do the right thing.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah i noticed that.... is there no way to work around this? I don't think they will change this any time soon....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe[src^='//www.opentable.com']").attr('src', function(i, oldsrc) {
        return "https:" + oldsrc;
    });
);
```

It waits until the document is ready, which should be after the new IFRAME is added to the DOM, then it replaces its `src` with one with the `https:` protocol.

Comment: Yup I ended up with the same thing! Thanks tho.

Comment: I'm just annoyed that I didn't think of this a day or two ago when someone else asked a similar question.